# Counting instances of values in an object using Array.prototype.reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

Here's an MDN example of **`Array.prototype.reduce()`** I'm not quite understand:

```
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tiff", "Bruce", "Alice"];

const countedNames = names.reduce((allNames, name) => {
    const currCount = allNames[name] ?? 0;
    return {
        ...allNames,
        [name]: currCount + 1,
    };
}, {});

// countedNames is:
// { 'Alice': 2, 'Bob': 1, 'Tiff': 1, 'Bruce': 1 }
```

What does `allNames[name]` mean in here? is this a array [attribute] syntax? I only known array[index], could you let me know the name of this form?

And why here's another {} at the end of below sentence:
`return{...allNames,[name]: currCount + 1,};}, {})`

Thank you!

Comment: That example is kind of weird looking at it now. There's no need to create a new object on each iteration as the accumulator is already an object and that's passed in on each iteration anyway.

Comment: [Nullish Coalescing Operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [Spread Syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) . Read also about [Destructuring Assignment `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the super useful  [Rest Parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (to not confuse the terms with different use-cases)

Answer (score 0):

```
const currCount = allNames[name] ?? 0
```

This is a use of the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). It means that the variable `currCount` will first try to be assigned the value of `allNames[name]`. However, if that results in a "nullish" value (in this case `undefined` because there hasn't been anything assigned in `allNames` for a specific `name`), then the variable gets assigned to `0`.

```
return {
...allNames,
};
```

This is a use of the spread operator and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It means that the a new object will be created with all the properties (keys and values) of the old `allNames` object.

```
[name]: currCount + 1,
```

This part says to create a new property with the key as a specific name and the value as the current count plus one. Combined with the snippet above, this will create a new object that's the same as `allNames`, except that the property with the key `name` will get overwritten, with the new value having an updated count.

Answer (score 0):

- `??` [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) Often used to **fallback** to a default value if the left-hand-side operand is `null` or **`undefined`**
- `...` [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) Used to (in your case) *reinsert, spread* an object properties and values into another object. Important to know is that the properties that follow that spread will override the previous properties values!

Your [`.reduce()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function "reduces" (*converts*) the input Array into an Object `{}` (— that *thing* (**second argument** AKA: *currentValue*) you noticed at the end of reduce's `}, {});`).
Since that *currentValue* object `{}` initially has no properties (it's "empty") you cannot increment a value to a non-existing property.

In the first iteration `allNames[name]` (being `allNames["Alice"]`) is `undefined` since there's no `"Alice"` property (AKA: *key*) in `allNames`. Therefore, you cannot increment something that is `undefined` (not an integer).

```
const currCount = allNames[name] ?? 0;
```

if `allNames[name]` returns `undefined` — the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` will make sure to **fallback** to the value of `0` - and stores it into `currCount`.

```js
  return {
    ...allNames,
    [name]: currCount + 1,
  };
```

The above just (uselessly!) [spreads `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `...allNames` object into a new Object `return {}` (that is then returned and reused in the next iteration as a modified `allNames`)  - and increments the number of a specific property `name` (being the currently iterated person's name).
Then **overrides** (by using `[name]: currCount + 1,`) any existing `[name]` property to an incremented value.

This *spreading* syntax is just a shorthand of [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
Here's an example:

```js
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tiff", "Bruce", "Alice"];

const countedNames = names.reduce((allNames, name) => {
  const currCount = allNames[name] ?? 0;
  return Object.assign({}, allNames, {[name]: currCount + 1});
}, {});

console.log(countedNames)
```

Here's a different (better, more legible) remake of the same:

```js
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tiff", "Bruce", "Alice"];

const countedNames = names.reduce((ob, name) => {
  ob[name] ??= 0; // if undefined, set that property and set value to 0
  ob[name] += 1;  // Increment value by 1
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(countedNames)
```

Which without using any fancy code is the same as doing:

```js
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tiff", "Bruce", "Alice"];

const countedNames = names.reduce((ob, name) => {
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    ob[name] = 0;
  }
  ob[name] += 1; // Increment it
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(countedNames)
```

which, without the `.reduce()` it's done like:

```js
const names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Tiff", "Bruce", "Alice"];

const countedNames = {};

names.forEach((name) => {
  if (!countedNames.hasOwnProperty(name)) { // If object has no such name, create it and assign value to 0
    countedNames[name] = 0;
  }
  countedNames[name] += 1; // Increment the value by 1
});

console.log(countedNames);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed advices, a question might stupid, could you tell me the meaning of "ob[name]"? does it equal to: `ob= {name: 0} ` ?  I haven't learned such syntax before

Comment: No, `name` is a variable that can hold any value. Say you have `const name = "Alice"`, if you then do `ob[name] = 0;` the output of that Object will be: `{"Alice": 0}` . That's just a way to set properties to an object given a variable value, `"Alice"` in that case is the property (AKA: *"Key"*) and `0` is the value.  (PS: You're very welcome :))

Comment: @GreenDog basically the trick is (as you can see from the `ob` output)  to create an Object with person names as properties and increment the integer assigned to every such person's name. You'll use that one pretty often in development, and as you can see it's useful to treat Names as Unique properties and then just assign and increment an integer for the purpose of counting.

Answer (score 0):

The (??) is called a ***Nullish coalescing operator***.
According to MDN, it is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

So allNames[name] ?? 0 is saying, "Return the value of allNames[name], but if it is null or undefined, return 0 instead.

It is similar to the ***Ternary Operator*** (?), but it's more terse.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```js
const allNames = [];

let currCount = allNames[name] ?? 0;

console.log(currCount);

currCount = (allNames[name]) ? allNames[name] : 0;

console.log(currCount);
```

It is also kind of similar to the ***Logical Disjuncton Operator*** or **Double Pipes** ( || ). This one returns the value of one of the specified operands.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

It is often used to set a default value and is used like:

```js
const allNames = [];
const value = allNames[name] || 0; 
console.log(value)
```

---

The (...) is called ***Spread Syntax***. It allows an iterable, such as an array or string, to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected.

In addition to what other answers have said, It's handy when you don't want to define a gazillion arguments for a function, or you don't know how many arguments are comming, or you don't know what is being passed to a callback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Here's an example:

```js
function callback(...args) {
    console.log(args);
  }
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => callback(event, 'foo'));
```